# Custom Wordpress User role can't add image into post

Tags: php, wordpress, roles

I created a custom User role in Wordpress and I gave the role the ability to upload files. However, once you upload the files and try to insert them into the post, nothing happens. Here are the set of roles I provided which I believe should give the user access to insert images into the post.

```
 function add_guide_author_role() {
     $role = get_role( 'guide_author' );
     // create if neccesary
     if (!$role) $role = add_role('guide_author', 'Guide Author'); 
     // add theme specific roles
     $role->add_cap('delete_posts');
     $role->add_cap('edit_posts');
     $role->add_cap('edit_published_posts');
     $role->add_cap('read');
     $role->add_cap('upload_files');
 }

 add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_guide_author_role');
```

Am I missing a `add_cap` to give them the ability to add the images they uploaded into the post?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you ever found the answer to this question, but if you change

```
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_guide_author_role');
```

to

```
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_guide_author_role');
```

you might find that the problem goes away.